# Sorting a table with R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a table in R and I sort it like this:

```
> x<-c("100","100","300","200","200","200")
> x
[1] "100" "100" "300" "200" "200" "200"
> table(x)
x
100 200 300 
  2   3   1 
> sort(table(x))
x
300 100 200 
  1   2   3
```

But my problem is that I would like to have it sorted by the numbers 300, 100, and 200. So I would like to know how to do it.

Comment: I mean, a function that could make this column usable, so i can operate with it.

Comment: Please show the desired result in your post

Comment: If you just need to manipulate the result of table, you can turn it into a `data.frame` (likely you are more familiar with it) using `as.data.frame(table(x))`. Note that the result is sorta transposed, so you might not like it...

Comment: Or just `rev(table(x))` if the answer below is what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `sort` by the names of the `table` output

```
tbl <- table(x)
tbl[order(-as.numeric(names(tbl)))]
```

Answer (score 19):

You can transfer the table to data.frame, and then use `arrange` function from the package `dplyr`.

```r
table(x) %>% 
        as.data.frame() %>% 
        arrange(desc(Freq))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution; it is based on simple R code and it works for any types of data, e.g. numeric or string. Hope it helps:

```
x <- c("100","100","300","200","200","200")
t <- table(x)

# you can sort based on any order you prefer
order_ind <- c("300","100","200")

t[order_ind]
```

[image]

Comment: omg... this is lovely, and also instructive on how access to the table works